# Powerpoint 2010 Multiple Instances

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

I have seen numerous posts on this subject here, but none seem to answer this issue directly. I want to control two instances of Powerpoint running on a second monitor.

The ideal solution looks like this:

```
PowerPoint.Application PPTViewer1 = new PowerPoint.Application();
PowerPoint.Application PPTViewer2 = new PowerPoint.Application();
```

I can do this manually, simply by starting two instances of PowerPoint, loading the presentation, and starting the slide show from each instance. I can toggle back and forth between the two slide shows manually, with each being brought to the front as expected.

So... how do I do this programatically using VSTO and C#?? Like others before me, I see that the Interop.PowerPoint interface will create only the single instance. If that were not the case, then I could achieve the results I am looking for easily enough.

Additionally, I am not looking for a third party component for this task.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It may appear that you're running multiple instances of Powerpoint, but you're not.  It only allows one instance of itself.   If you see two instances of Powerpnt.exe in the task list, as sometimes happens, it means that something's gone wrong and left a zombie in memory.

Comment: Great observation, Stephen. I just verified that, and while it appears that I can open two instances, there is but a single instance of the executable in Task Mangler. Unfortunately, that does not get me any closer to my goal. Sigh.

Comment: Each running slide show will be represented by a member of the SlideShowWindows collection.  Depending on what you need to do, you might be able to get a reference to a slide show window object for each slide show you fire off, then manipulate those.

Answer (score 0):

May not be totally ideal but [here is a reference](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2008/06/multiple-instances-of-powerpoint.html?m=1) that suggested to start an instance as a different user (Note that this site is for PowerPoint 2007).

```
runas /user:username "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\POWER PNT.EXE"
```

Comment: I have seen that option as well in my investigation. This appears to apply to versions prior to PP 2010, as I can start multiple instances of the app without this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the Powerpoint COM object shares the same fullscreen display window. I know of no method to switch which presentation has that window

The solution is to host the Powerpoint display in your own window

This therefore allows you to scale the window and show multiple presentations on one monitor, or move it from one monitor to another?

e.g.

```
var display1 = new FullScreenDisplay(); // A form with BorderStyle = None
display1.Show();
application1 = new PowerPoint.Application();
presentation1 = application1.Presentations.Open2007(....);
var slideShowSettings1 = presentation1.SlideShowSettings;
slideShowSettings1.ShowType = PowerPoint.PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeSpeaker;
var slideShowWindow1 = slideShowSettings1.Run();
IntPtr hwnd1 = (IntPtr)slideShowWindow1.HWND;
SetParent(hwnd1, display1.Handle);

var display2 = new FullScreenDisplay();
display2.Show();
application2 = new PowerPoint.Application();
presentation2 = application2.Presentations.Open2007(....);
var slideShowSettings2 = presentation2.SlideShowSettings;
slideShowSettings2.ShowType = PowerPoint.PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeSpeaker;
var slideShowWindow2 = slideShowSettings2.Run();
IntPtr hwnd2 = (IntPtr)slideShowWindow2.HWND;
SetParent(hwnd2, display2.Handle);

display1.BringToFront(); // to show slideshow 1
// or
display2.BringToFront(); // to show slideshow 2

// To advance a slide
presentation1.SlideShowWindow.View.Next();
// or
presentation2.SlideShowWindow.View.Next();

// To exit, note order!
presentation2.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit();
presentation1.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit();
Application.Exit();
```

This is a hack, and may not work in future versions of Powerpoint?

You also need this import

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Comment: Thanks, TFD. I will dig into it and let you know how I progress.

Comment: Of course display1 etc could be a panel on a form, not just a form

Comment: I am finally getting back to this project. Your solution gets a 50%, as I discovered a couple of significant issues; first, this does not appear to work on 64 bit, and I am still researching that. More importantly, it points out the glaring need to implement the active document server. This is the only way that I have found to execute animations and slide shows. As your code stand above, the first page of the presentation WILL display, but without the server being activated. See next comment....

Comment: I am off to see if I can deconstruct the code here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118676/Embedding-PowerPoint-presentation-player-into-a-WP , which implements the desired functionality in a very convoluted manner of C, C++, C#, and then back to unmanaged C++. I was hoping for a simpler solution than this. Thanks, TFD.

Comment: Well, it could be that I had something horked up on the 64 bit side. When I resolve the animations issue, and have it roking, I will go back to 64 bit and test. FWIW, I found some interesting bits here as well: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/739d453e-092e-46c3-8bc2-1836d5a9b4f8. It looks like using the pptviewer may resolve the clunkiness of starting the presentation and then moving it to the second monitor. Though you might be interested.