# Embedding .exe for use inside a VB Form

Tags: .net, winforms

I need to embed a  notepad.exe inside a windows form[ just like embedding a flash inside a web page] ... Is this possible

Comment: How about using a `TextBox() {MultiLine = true}` instead? Unless you truly are trying something malicious here...

Comment: It's possible. But why do you want to do this? Maybe there are better solutions. Anyhow, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360758/embedding-a-powerpoint-show-into-a-c-sharp-application/11391508#11391508).

Comment: Mr. Steak tat code is not working......pls help